# Query returns overly obtuse structure. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I run this simple query:

```
"SELECT url FROM bookmarks"
```

which returns an array of objects.

I am then forced to run:

```
public function getUrls()
{
    // runs query above

    $result = $this->o_database->_pdoQuery('multiple', 'pull_urls');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        $temp[$i] = $value['url'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

to simplify the structure into an array of urls.

Is there a way to get this from the query and not have to process in in PHP?

Comment: This is because your query could've returned more than one row.  So you need the result to be an array of arrays.  P.S. You can just do `$temp[] = $value['url'];` instead of using `$i`.

Comment: I see you are using PDO, check out PDOStatement::fetchAll and if it works with your framework.

Comment: @pure_code.mom: No, I just meant you eliminate the `$i` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PDO, you would use [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) using `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` like this:

```
$urls = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Comment: @pure_code.mom Usually by reading the manual and then making small hello world applications to learn how to apply them :)

Comment: @pure_code.mom Personally I would find it more confusing if changing the query would also change the result type :)

Answer (score 2):

i think you shoud try with PDOStatement.fetchAll (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)